# why does the runtime version of my android studio say AMD64 on my Windows system?

Tags: android-studio, x86-64, windows64

I'm new to developing apps for the Android OS platform (on Windows version of Android Studio) so I'm pretty ignorant. While trying to debug a "toy" app, I noticed that the About box (of Android Studio) says the runtime version is 11.0.10 ...**amd64**. The "amd64" gave me pause. Is this, in fact, correct for the Windows64 installation of Android Studio (Artic Fox | 2020.3.1)?

Comment: The Intel x86_64 architecture is a re-implementation of the amd64 architecture.   Intel abandoned the x86 architecture for its 64bit cpu Itanium, rightly dubbed Itanic.  During that time, AMD came up with a 64bit variant of the ancient x86 architecture.   Once itanic started sinking in earnest, intel had to implement its own version of the amd64 instruction set.

Comment: @mevets - thanks for the history!! i was wondering how x86_64 and amd64 differed because i've seen them used interchangeably.